# Java/Android xml parsing causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a problem with parsing XML file on android.

My examples.xml file look like this:

```
<categories>
    <example>something</example>
</categories>
```

And my Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.examples));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); //here it throws NullPointerException
```

It throws a NullPointerException when I try to normalize().

I am inspired by this simple tutorial http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/getdocumentelementnormalize/

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: the value of doc is most likely null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your xml file to the `res/raw` folder, then try this:

```
Document doc = db.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.examples));
```

Let me know if that works.

EDIT: if you look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29 it basically says you can only use that on drawable, sound and raw resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try XmlPullParser. It's a little bit easier, I think.

[XmlPullParser | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Project|Clean - it might not be getting the raw XML from your resources. Eclipse seems a bit flaky that way, I sometimes change code & it doesn't pick up the changes until its cleaned.